# Canvas buffering screen size

Tags: java, canvas, size, buffering

I wrote these code in a  class which extends Canvas.
(please have a look at the pictures at these links if you don't want to read, i can't post pictures directly because of stackoverflow reputation or something)
http://tinypic.com/r/oaw3u8/5
http://tinypic.com/r/24g9ldz/5

```
    final static int WIDTH = 800;
    final static int HEIGHT = 600;
    Dimension SIZE = new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    Game() {
    setPreferredSize(SIZE);
    **
    **
    *
    *
}


    public void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.cyan);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
**g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());**
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
```

question is about the double-stared line of code, which is used for refreshing the screen by drawing a screen-size rectangle. 
**at the first time, my code was 
        g.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
then i notice the balck rectangle was smaller then the screen. there was a minor,about 1 inch, margin at the right inside of the frame.(i might use "margin" wrong but i hope you get what i mean)
 so i used getWidth(),getHeight() instead of using the exact variable WIDTH and HEIGHT.
and it worked well,
i don't know the reason why ?
please help me why is this happening, are variable not accurate in this situation? or what .
thank you very much

Comment: How do you actually set the width and height of the Canvas?

Comment: in construction of this class,      setPreferredSize(SIZE);      sorry i forgot to mention that. BTW, there is a JFrame in main method ,contain this canvas class and pack() at the end ;

Comment: Dimension SIZE = new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT)